# Unicode issue when ssh'ing from GNOME Terminal to OS X

Tags: osx, gnome-terminal, unicode

When I ssh from GNOME Terminal (tried different 14.04/16.04 distros, currently on Mint 18) to OS X, I have a unicode issue, e.g. the prompt is not properly displayed.

[image]

On OS X, I have bash 4.x as a default shell, installed via macports (and it's working fine when used from OS X Terminal).

By accident, I found out that if I run `bash` once I have ssh'ed in, the new shell don't have the unicode issue (until I `exit` to the previous shell).

Any ideas ?

(BTW, my locales variables are all set to en_US.UTF-8).

Comment: The nature of the problem isn't clear from the description.

Comment: I tried to copy/paste the mangled prompt, but the displayed characters are not properly copied/pasted.

Comment: A screenshot helps.  More complicated, you could capture the characters using `script` and paste the `cat -v typescript` as more-or-less readable text.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I added a screenshot.

Comment: This is not a Unicode issue at all. OSC 1337 are custom to iTerm2's shell integration and are not supported by gnome-terminal.

Comment: Then it's a bug in gnome-terminal (if it doesn't recognize a validly-formatted OSC, then it should echo nothing).  A good answer would point out when it was fixed.

Comment: @egmont oops, I should have tested to remove shell integration from my `.profile`

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the problem between Debian 8.9 with Bash 4.3.30 and Gnome Terminal 3.14.3.

The comment from rhangaun gave the answer: The problem is the `.iterm2_shell_integration.bash` integration. For iterm2 on mac it was initialized in my .profile file on the server.